# Dynamic Google doughnut chart from sql query data

Tags: json, sql-server, ajax, vb.net, google-visualization

I want to make a Google doughnut chart populated with data from a sql query.

I searched for example code but has not been able to make a chart appear.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Global variable to hold data
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(DrawDonut);

        $(function DrawDonut() {

            var options = {
                pieHole: 0.4,      
                colors: ['#286090', '#d7d7d7']  
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetChartData',
                data: '{}',
                success:
                    function (response) {
                        drawchart(response.d);
                    },

                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
                    }
            });
        })
            function drawchart(dataValues) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'UnitID');
            data.addColumn('number', 'TotalUse');
            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].UnitID, dataValues[i].TotalUse]);
            }
            new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart')).
                draw(data, { title: "Use distributed on units" });
        }    
    </script>
```

Html:

```
<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

Code behind:

```
<WebMethod()> 
Public Shared Function GetChartData(ByVal MemberIndex As String) As List(Of Object)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Log.[UnitID], COUNT(*) As [TotalUse] FROM Log WHERE (MemberIndex_Log = @MemberIndex AND (GramSup1 + GramSup2) > 0 AND Log.[UnitID] > 5000) GROUP BY Log.[UnitID]"
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
    Dim chartData As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)()
    chartData.Add(New Object() {"UnitID", "TotalUse"})
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberIndex", Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session("MemberIndex")))
            con.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    chartData.Add(New Object() {sdr("UnitID"), sdr("TotalUse")})
                End While
            End Using

           con.Close()
           Return chartData
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

I want a dynamic doughnut chart to appear, showing the use of the units (typically from 2 10 units) distributed on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

first, `jsapi` is an old version of google charts and should no longer be used.

use `loader.js` instead, note the path...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` statement.

---

next, google charts will wait for the page to load by default.
no need to place your code inside the jquery short-hand document ready function --> `$(function () {`
placing the `DrawDonut` function inside the ready function,
takes it out of scope from the google callback.
since it cannot be reached, it does not run.

---

last, the `success` & `error` callbacks on `$.ajax` have been deprecated,
use the `done` & `fail` promises instead.

---

recommend setup similar to the following snippet...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
  }).then(function () {
    var options = {
      title: 'Use distributed on units',
      pieHole: 0.4,
      colors: ['#286090', '#d7d7d7'],
      width: 900,
      height: 600
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: 'Default.aspx/GetChartData',
      data: '{}'
    }).done(function (response) {
      drawchart(response.d);
    }).fail(function () {
      console.log('Error loading data! Please try again.');
    });

    function drawchart(dataValues) {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'UnitID');
      data.addColumn('number', 'TotalUse');
      for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].UnitID, dataValues[i].TotalUse]);
      }
      new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart')).
        draw(data, options);  // <-- use options already defined above
    }
  });
</script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

note: you are defining your `options` object, here...

```
var options = {
    pieHole: 0.4,      
    colors: ['#286090', '#d7d7d7']  
};
```

but not using it to draw the chart, here...

```
draw(data, { title: "Use distributed on units" });
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but unfortunately, it is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: will you please edit the question with the latest version of your code?

Comment: I have used exactly the code you proposed. In order to avoid any potential conflict with other JavaScript (my page is otherwise using Jquery.3.3.1) or other, I placed the code in a separate aspx/aspx.vb pages, but also without result. I have made a separate query and bound to a gridview to test that it result in the envisaged table: column headers are

Comment: did you replace `https://www.google.com/jsapi` with `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`? are there any errors in the browser's console (press F12 on most)?

Comment: Yes. I also made a separate query and bound it to a gridview to test that it result in the envisaged table that should form the basis for the donut: Column headers: UnitID and TotalUse, Rowcontent (examples): SL005 and 126, SL004 and 245, SL231 and 87. I imagine from that a doughnut with three pieces with a relative size of 126, 245 and 87.

Comment: OK, errors are: i) SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'defaults' of undefined or null reference jquery-3.3.1.js (3827,3), ii) SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'drawchart' is not defined localhost:49962 (144,11), iii) SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference jquery.blockUI.js (27,1), iv) SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference donut (40,23).

Comment: I discovered that the url was unfortunately not changed to the separate page I call donut. Now the error message is alone nr. iv) above.