# signalR - how to show realtime chart

Tags: signalr

finally I know how to call the method in the server and the client will refresh the chart. if you update data on table, the chart will adjust automatically. the code as below:

this is my html code:

```html
<div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../signalR/hubs"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //proxy created on the fly                    
                var job = $.connection.statisticsHub;

                //declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it                    
                job.client.displayStatus = function () {                        
                    getData();
                };

                //start the connection                    
                $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('now connected');
                    //execute function in client from server
                    job.server.show();
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    console.log('error nih: ' + error);
                });
            });                
            
            function getData() {
                //alert("from getData");
                google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function drawChart() {
                    var options = {
                        title: 'USA City Distribution'
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetChartData",
                        data: '{}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (r) {
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);
                            chart.draw(data, options);
                        },
                        failure: function (r) {
                            alert(r.d);
                        },
                        error: function (r) {
                            alert(r.d);
                        }
                    });
                }                    
            }
        </script>
        <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
        </div>
```

this is Hub:

```html
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace TutorialGooglePieChart
{
public class StatisticsHub : Hub
{
    public void Show()        
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatisticsHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
    }
}
}
```

this is my cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TutorialGooglePieChart
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<object> GetChartData()
        {

            string query = "SELECT Name, Quantity FROM [dbo].[Products]";

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
            chartData.Add(new object[]
            {
        "Name", "Quantity"
            });
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    con.Open();                                        

                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            chartData.Add(new object[]
                            {
                        sdr["Name"], sdr["Quantity"]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return chartData;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                StatisticsHub myHub = new StatisticsHub();
                myHub.Show();

            }
        }      
    }
}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, the java script looks okay.

Your method needs to be updated, remove static from your method, not positive but I think that is where your main problem is.  Comment out the IHubContext as I don't believe it is needed since you are within the hub. I think that is for calling methods (in your hub) from other classes.

Also, changing Clients.All to Clients.Caller. It would not make sense to update everyone's chart when anyone connects. Rather only the calling client.

Try changing to this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace TutorialGooglePieChart
{
    public class StatisticsHub : Hub
    {
        public void Show()        
        {
            //IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatisticsHub>();
            //context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
            context.Clients.Caller.displayStatus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need context for invoke context.clients. you're right, when i remove statistic, i don't meet error function, but why the chart still not shown.

Comment: I found the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303716/dynamic-google-doughnut-chart-from-sql-query-data/54308726#54308726)